How to backup the whole group chat in telegram with telethon?
I would like to clone or backup or forward the messages (including files, videos) to another group. The groups have topics.
What I have tried
I tried to use a Telegram Bot with telethon but some functions cannot be accessed by bot. So, I used a phone number, actually three. They all got banned. Maybe my codes were very bad, and I was sending too many requests. I would love to get some codes that will definitely work, please. I have only one telegram account left. Thanks, guys.

If there are some other ways around that cost no money, I am open to try it.

Bans are fairly common because a lot of people use the library to spam. If they're legitimate numbers and accounts, you can probably get them back https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/824.
